# Font weight in fabric.js library for HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I've been playing with canvas and the awesome fabric library. I can't get text to display in anything other than the normal weight. i.e.

```
    var text2 = new fabric.Text('tseting', {
    fontsize: 50,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontStyle = 'bold',
    left: 100, 
    top: 100,
    fill:"#FF0000"
});

canvas2.add(text2);
```

The '**bold**' tag doesn't get applied. When I created the `font.js` file suing *cufon*, I included the bold and italic fonts. Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: fontStyle = 'bold' you have used wrong property that means you should use bold property with fontWeight

Answer (score 5):

You've used the wrong property, and a typo ( the `fontStyle = 'bold',`).
Use this instead:

```
var text2 = new fabric.Text('testing', {
    fontSize: 50,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    left: 100, 
    top: 100,
    fill: "#FF0000"
});

canvas2.add(text2);
```

Answer (score 2):

`fontStyle` refers to italic / normal.

Try `fontWeight: bold` or `fontWeight: 700`?